# How to grab second occurring name from xml api data with C#

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, api

I'm trying to grab the high and low from [this api](http://api.wunderground.com/api/ea4bb7e7839782da/forecast/q/CA/San_Francisco.xml), I am able to get the High, but can't figure out what to do to get the Low, which is the second occurring item with the name "fahrenheit", how could I do this using the same method I used for getting the High?

```
if (xmlForecast.Name == "fahrenheit" && i == 0)
{
   i++;
   xmlHigh = xmlForecast.ReadString();
}
```

Comment: You are not working with XML, you should deserialize JSON you got from api response.

Comment: My apologies I changed the link, I forgot to replace .json with .xml, it's fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want solution using XML response, here it is:

First, you'll need to create classes which will represent XML response.

```
[XmlRoot("response")]
public class Response
{
    [XmlElement("version")]
    public string Version { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("termsofService")]
    public string TermsOfService { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("features")]
    public Features Features { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("forecast")]
    public Forecast Forecast { get; set; }
}

public class Features
{
    [XmlElement("forecast")]
    public int Forecast { get; set; }
}

public class Forecast
{
    [XmlElement("txt_forecast")]
    public TxtForecast TxtForecast { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("simpleforecast")]
    public SimpleForecast SimpleForecast { get; set; }
}

public class TxtForecast
{
    [XmlElement("date")]
    public string Date { get; set; }
    [XmlArray("forecastdays")]
    [XmlArrayItem("forecastday")]
    public List<ForecastDay> ForecastDays { get; set; }
}

public class ForecastDay
{
    [XmlElement("period")]
    public int Period { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("icon")]
    public string Icon { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("icon_url")]
    public string IconUrl { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("fcttext")]
    public string FctText { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("fcttext_metric")]
    public string FctTextMetric { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("pop")]
    public string Pop { get; set; }
}


public class SimpleForecast
{
    [XmlArray("forecastdays")]
    [XmlArrayItem("forecastday")]
    public List<ForecastDay2> ForecastDays { get; set; }
}

public class ForecastDay2
{
    [XmlElement("date")]
    public Date Date { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("period")]
    public int Period { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("high")]
    public High High { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("low")]
    public Low Low { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("conditions")]
    public string Conditions { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("icon")]
    public string Icon { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("icon_url")]
    public string IconUrl { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("skyicon")]
    public string SkyIcon { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("pop")]
    public int Pop { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("qpf_allday")]
    public QpfAllday QpfAllDay { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("qpf_day")]
    public QpfDay QpfDay { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("qpf_night")]
    public QpfNight QpfNight { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("snow_allday")]
    public SnowAllday SnowAllday { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("snow_day")]
    public SnowDay SnowDay { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("snow_night")]
    public SnowNight SnowNight { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("maxwind")]
    public MaxWind MaxWind { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("avewind")]
    public AveWind AveWind { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("avehumidity")]
    public int AveHumidity { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("maxhumidity")]
    public int MaxHumidity { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("minhumidity")]
    public int MinHumidity { get; set; }
}

public class Date
{
    [XmlElement("epoch")]
    public string Epoch { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("pretty")]
    public string Pretty { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("day")]
    public int Day { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("month")]
    public int Month { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("year")]
    public int Year { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("yday")]
    public int Yesterday { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("hour")]
    public int Hour { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("min")]
    public string Min { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("sec")]
    public int Sec { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("isdst")]
    public string Isdst { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("monthname")]
    public string MonthName { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("monthname_short")]
    public string MonthNameShort { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("weekday_short")]
    public string WeekdayShort { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("weekday")]
    public string Weekday { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("ampm")]
    public string AmPM { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("tz_short")]
    public string TzShort { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("tz_long")]
    public string TzLong { get; set; }
}

public class High
{
    [XmlElement("fahrenheit")]
    public string Fahrenheit { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("celsius")]
    public string Celsius { get; set; }
}

public class Low
{
    [XmlElement("fahrenheit")]
    public string Fahrenheit { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("celsius")]
    public string Celsius { get; set; }
}

public class QpfAllday
{
    [XmlElement("@in")]
    public double Inches { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("mm")]
    public int Milimeters { get; set; }
}

public class QpfDay
{
    [XmlElement("@in")]
    public double Inches { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("mm")]
    public int Milimeters { get; set; }
}

public class QpfNight
{
    [XmlElement("@in")]
    public double Inches { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("mm")]
    public int Milimeters { get; set; }
}

public class SnowAllday
{
    [XmlElement("@in")]
    public double Inches { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("cm")]
    public double Centimeters { get; set; }
}

public class SnowDay
{
    [XmlElement("@in")]
    public double Inches { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("cm")]
    public double Centimeters { get; set; }
}

public class SnowNight
{
    [XmlElement("@in")]
    public double Inches { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("cm")]
    public double Centimeters { get; set; }
}

public class MaxWind
{
    [XmlElement("mph")]
    public int Mph { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("kph")]
    public int Kph { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("dir")]
    public string Direction { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("degrees")]
    public int Degrees { get; set; }
}

public class AveWind
{
    [XmlElement("mph")]
    public int Mph { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("kph")]
    public int Kph { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("dir")]
    public string Direction { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("degrees")]
    public int Degrees { get; set; }
}
```

Secondly, you need to deserialize XML into `Response`

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    using (var stream = await client.GetStreamAsync("http://api.wunderground.com/api/ea4bb7e7839782da/forecast/q/CA/San_Francisco.xml"))
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Response));
        var response = (Response)serializer.Deserialize(stream);

        var simpleForecast = response.Forecast.SimpleForecast;
        var forecastDays = simpleForecast.ForecastDays;
        var latestForecastDay = forecastDays.Last();
        var latestHighFahrenheit = latestForecastDay.High.Fahrenheit;
        var latestLowFahrenheit = latestForecastDay.Low.Fahrenheit;
    }
}
```

I am using `XmlSerializer` but you can also use `DataContractSerializer` which is newer. If you decide to use `DataContractSerializer` keep in mind that you'll need to replace `XmlElement` attributes with `DataContract` and `DataMember`.

Note: I've intentionally added few unnecessary steps and variable declarations, so you can see clearly what's going on here.